# How does this JS sort when it has a function inside that returns multiple things?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I created a secondary sort and its working but I don't understand how.

```
    this.report.sort((a, b) => {
        if(a[col] > b[col]) return 1;
        if(a[col] < b[col]) return -1;
        if(a[secondaryFilter] > b[secondaryFilter]) return  1;
        if(a[secondaryFilter] < b[secondaryFilter]) return -1;
    });
```

I thought when the sort sees the first return, it would exit the sort. How does it reach the secondary filter sort?

The code works and I learned the syntax online but I don't get how it works.

Comment: Oops let me remove that. I removed the ternary part of it but forgot to remove that section.

Comment: It *will* exit as soon as any `return` is reached. If the latter `secondaryFilter` lines have any affect, that means the previous 2-3 `return`s were never reached. That could be because the items being compared were equal, or `undefined`.

Comment: Are you really asking if it's possible for neither `expr1 < expr2` and `expr1 > expr2` to be true?  The `<` and `>` operators are mutually exclusive but they don't cover all possibilities, such as when they are equal (or when they are incomparable because of `NaN` or other JS weirdnesses).  Or are you asking something else?

Comment: ask chatGPT....

Comment: To make your sort actually technically correct, you should also add a `return 0` at the end, returning `undefined` might be treated like 0, but the spec does explicitly say 0..  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: @Keith I also thought `return 0` is required by the specs, but based on [23.1.3.30.2 CompareArrayElements ( x, y, comparefn )](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-comparearrayelements) this is not the case.  The `4. b.` returns `0` in case the return value of `comparefn` will result in a `NaN` after `ToNumber`. (I, however, would  also suggest always adding the `return 0`)

Comment: @t.niese  Oh, right yeah.  I suppose this is where MDN doesn't give you the full picture..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for all the replies! I was having a really bad brainfart and couldn't comprehend that there is a situation where the first two ifs can not be met. I'll make sure to add return 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the root of your confusion:

> I thought when the sort sees the first return, it would exit the sort

This is **wrong**. It will exit processing comparing two items in the array. However it has many other items it needs to compare so the sort function proceeds to get two more items in the array and pass it to the function.

Comment: Yup I totally get it now! I was having a major brain fart when I asked the question and couldn't understand how it reaches the third and fourth if statements